# How to find $f(z)$ if $f$ its an entire function

Tags: complex-analysis

So the problem is I have to find $f(z)$ with $f$ is an entire function such that $\vert{f(z)-e^z\sin(2z)}\vert \lt 4$

And now I dont know what I should do , I only have the information that  entire function mean that the function itself is analytic on entire plane , hence there exist neighborhood $\vert{z-z_0}\vert \lt \delta$ . So what should I do to find $f(z)$?

Comment: Do you know Liouville's theorem?

Comment: No I dont , but know I'll check my textbook looking for that theorem

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** by Liouville's theorem $f(z)=C+e^z \sin 2z$ with $|C|< 4$.

Comment: what if I defined $f(0)=1 \to C=1$ is that right ?

Comment: @ZnikDzulqarnain yeah

Comment: why $f(z)=C+e^zsin2z$ and not $f(z)=C-e^zsin2z$?

Comment: Can we say $f(z)+e^zsin2z=C$, $e^zsin2z$ is entire and $f(z)+e^zsin2z=C$ so $f(z)$ is entire too?

Comment: @gbox we know that $f-blah$ is bounded so $f-blah=C$.